# Can I project the result of my query to the model generated by EF?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a method something like below :

```
 public IEnumerable<CountryEF> GetAllCountry( )
    {


        using (Context context  = new Context() )
        {

            List<CountryEF> countries = context.COUNTRY.Select(c =>

                 new CountryEF()
                 {
                     ID = c.ID,
                     Description = c.DESCRIPTION,
                     CURRENCYEF = c.CURRENCYEF
                 }

            ).ToList<CountryEF>();

            return countries;
        }


    }
```

Where COUNTRYEF is a Model Class Generated by Entity Framework which looks like this :

```
public partial class COUNTRYEF
{
    public COUNTRYEF()
    {

    }

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
    public virtual CURRENCY CURRENCYEF { get; set; }

}
```

When ever I do this I get Exception. So as a fallback I have to create another class which is just a copy-paste of above class like this below :

```
    public class COUNTRYVM //view model class
    {
        public COUNTRYVM()
        {

        }

        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public virtual CURRENCY CURRENCYEF { get; set; }

    }
```

And then my query becomes like this :

```
    public IEnumerable<CountryVM> GetAllCountry( )
    {


        using (Context context  = new Context() )
        {

            List<CountryVM> countries = context.COUNTRY.Select(c =>

                 new CountryVM()
                 {
                     ID = c.ID,
                     Description = c.DESCRIPTION,
                     CURRENCYEF = c.CURRENCYEF
                 }

            ).ToList<CountryVM>();

            return countries;
        }

    }
```

And the above solution works fine and good. But Do I really want to replicate the Model classes generated by Entity Framework like `public partial class COUNTRYEF` to something like  `public class COUNTRYVM`. I really don't want to do code duplication.

What are the possible solutions for this ? 
Anonymous properties also dont. I had tried the below solution :

```
   public IEnumerable GetAllCountry( )
    {


        using (Context context  = new Context() )
        {

            var countries = context.COUNTRY.Select(c =>

                 new  //Anonymous Projection 
                 {
                     ID = c.ID,
                     Description = c.DESCRIPTION,
                     CURRENCYEF = c.CURRENCYEF
                 }

            ).ToList();

            return countries;
        }

    }
```

But then I cannot access the ID , Description and CurrencyEF in my Views and Controllers!!

Comment: Your first piece should just be `List<CountryEF> countries = context.COUNTRY.ToList();` . Be more specific about the error you got.

Comment: @henkHolterman : Doesn't context.Country.ToList() returns all the columns. What should I do if I want only few of the columns.

Comment: http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/09/anonymous-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-using-dynamics/

I got my answer why anonymous type doesn't work.

Comment: What is the exception you get for the first try?

Comment: If you don't want all columns you *should* create a view model. Don't work with half-baked entities. At the consuming side you'll always have to be aware of which properties can ans can't be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework doesn't allow creating classes of the Entity inside it's projection.  Something to do with hard for it to track which entities it should be tracking.  The work around I use.  Instead of copy and pasting the class just subclass it.

```
public partial class CountryEFSub : CountryEF
{
}


public IEnumerable<CountryEF> GetAllCountry( )
{

    using (Context context  = new Context() )
    {

        return context.COUNTRY.AsNoTracking().Select(c =>

             new CountryEFSub()
             {
                 ID = c.ID,
                 Description = c.DESCRIPTION,
                 CURRENCYEF = c.CURRENCYEF
             }

        ).AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

This tricked worked in EF 5.  I haven't used it with any version else.  Also noticed you can leave the method type still as CountryEF.

You could create a T4 to create all the subclasses for you.  Also if you need help with the projections I believe AutoMapper now supports IQueryable.  Otherwise you can write the projections by hand or with expresison trees.

Comment: I think this is a terrible "solution". It still has all the downsides of replicating classes (which the OP explicitly tries to avoid) and none of the advantages of dedicated view models.

Comment: Well I can't please everyone.  I just wanted to point out that inheritance != replication.  Just like Reputation != learning

Comment: @Gert Arnold : chill people. I am just trying to learn. I don't think any solution is terrible. Its kind of harsh thing to say.